# Why don't people write literally the "at" symbol?

Tags: html, email, character

I usually see that people, in the Internet, don't writes the *at* symbol (@) for their e-mail accounts or similar.

They do things like this: "my_username(AT)domain(DOT)com", and not "my_username@domain.com"

Do you know why is it? I've investigated a lot and I could't find any answer. Thanks :D

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer questions. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more information about the types of questions that are proper to ask here. Please follow those guidelines. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a way of preventing spam (for robots that scans emails with an @ symbol).

Answer (score 1):

Simple: they are trying to protect their e-mails from autmatic collection by robots in attempt to protect themselves from SPAM

Answer (score 1):

A lot of simple *bots* on the internet farm emails from various websites. When they are in their simplest form (e.g. bob@website.com) they are easily picked up. By changing some parts of it, such as the @ to (AT) can help to prevent such bots realising it is an email address.

However - most bots are smarter, and you would need to go to further measures to protect your email address on a website, such as cloaking it with JavaScript.

Lots of examples on email cloaking via JavaScript can be found here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+email+cloak

Hope that answers your question :-).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of spam bots. In general they're programmed to scan the web looking for email addresses, generally written with the @ symbol, that they include in some database used for spam bombing. This is a easy-to-do first attempt to reduce spam mails.. :D

(Best techniques for safe email posting on the net are made with Javascript)